# Speeding Rails ActiveRecord Commits

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm dealing with a fairly large amount of data and I was hoping for some advice speeding up record creation. In my test I created about 300k rows with about 9 columns and it took far longer than I was hoping.

I basically have a list of objects for each user that I use data from to generate a longer, different list.

The basic structure in my controller is as follows:

```
def create
  @list = Thing.all.to_array
  @list.each do |item|
    @new_thing   = NewThing.new
    @new_thing.a = item.a
    @new_thing.b = item.b 
    @new_thing.save
  end
end
```

What can I do to speed this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways that you can accomplish this.

1. Wrap everything in a Transaction: `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`
2. Write raw SQL: `NewThing.connection.execute "INSERT INTO new_things (a, b) values (a, b)"`
3. Write a mass insert:

```
def create
  @inserts = []
  @list = Thing.all.to_a
  @list.each do |item|
    @inserts.push "(#{item.a}, #{item.b})"
  end
  sql = "INSERT INTO new_things (`a`, `b`) VALUES #{@inserts.join(", ")}"
  NewThing.execute(sql)
end
```

The mass insert is going to be the fastest to run, but the hardest to write and understand. Trade offs.

Also, since you've got this sitting in a create action, you're best bet is to move it into a background job so that your large db operations aren't holding up the user.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to use direct query if you want to reduce time.

```
def create
  NewThing.execute("INSERT INTO new_things (a,b) SELECT a, b FROM things")
end
```

Above sql statement works with mysql.